# Origin of the babytalk phrase goo goo ga ga?

Tags: etymology

Strange question: I don't know if onomatopoeia are said to have a proper etymology as such, but I was wondering if anyone knows the approximate first usage of the babytalk phrase goo goo ga ga?

Comment: *Goo-goo* (without *ga-ga*) as a representation of baby talk is at least as early as 1863 in *Harper's* magazine, according to the *Oxford English Dictionary*. The same dictionary defines *ga-ga* as a senile person. I don't know when the two sounds were first used together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onomatopoeic  ***[goo-goo-ga-ga](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/goo_goo_ga_ga)*** appears to be the combination of two imitative expression of babbling  talking. Goo-goo has an older origin, from the mid 19th century while ga-ga, which may derive from French, is from the early 20th century:

***[Goo goo](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/goo-goo):***

> - Infantile; cooing : talking goo-goo talk to her, like you would to a baby (1863+)

(The Dictionary of American Slang)

Wiktionary suggests an alternative origin:

> - Possibly from the Tagalog gugus, "tutelary spirit." ***Adapted as an ethnic slur by American troops during the Filipino-American War***

***[Ga-ga](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gaga?s=t):*** adj.

> - "crazy, silly," 1920, probably from French gaga "senile, foolish," ***probably imitative of meaningless babbling.***

(Collins Dictionary)

Comment: I wonder if goo-goo is a universal thing. Do Chinese parents say goo-goo to their babies as well, for example?